# serving wrong serverName

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost

A conf file of httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\lsapp\public"
  ServerName lsapp.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\codeigniter\bladetemplate\public"
    ServerName bladetemplate.test
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-conf file

```
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"

Listen 80

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so

LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so

LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so

LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so

LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


ServerAdmin admin@example.com

ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/lsapp/public"
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/lsapp/public">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule php5_module>

    PHPIniDir "C:/php"
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

This is an hosts file of window system:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       lsapp.test
127.0.0.2       bladetemplate.test
```

When i open up my browser write the bladetemplate.test host. it fetches the lsapp.test data. what wrong with i can't figure out check out my conf files above.All my ServerName and DocumentRoot is right.I am developing a laravel application. i have checked my files and folders correctly.

Comment: what's your reason für mapping your `bladetemplate.test` hostname to `127.0.0.2`?

Comment: i thought it will work if i changed the ip address but it did not.

Comment: i also checked on this 127.0.0.1 ip address. but it is serving the wrong directory.

Comment: You forgot to include your httpd-vhosts.conf file in your httpd.conf file.  The only include directive I see is for proxy-html.conf.  So it uses the DocumentRoot defined in httpd.conf, which happens to be the same value as your first VirtualHost

Comment: so what should i do? @Nic3500

Comment: In your httpd.conf file, at the end, add `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.  This will ensure your apache loads your configuration file and uses your VirtualHosts.

Comment: is it need to be write in `<IfModule></IfModule>` tag in httpd.conf file at the end?

Comment: No need, the Include directive is part of the core of Apache, so just the Include line will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days long journey i come up with the solution of my problem.So it was not on webserver side problem it is the copy/paste issue. 
I copy the existing project(laravel app) into my bladetemplate. so there is so much dependency that did not load because of i did not run some command like `php artisan key:generate, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan migrate` and some other.
so if you copy/paste your project make sure run the above commands or download the entire new project by issuing this command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourProjectName`.